# How do I compute $\cos$ and $\sin$ in a given interval if I know $\tan$?

Tags: trigonometry

$$ \tan x = -\frac{2}{3} $$

when $\dfrac{5\pi}{2} < x < 3\pi$.

I understand this, but I don't know how to calculate the two other functions' values, $\cos x$, $\sin x$, using $\tan x$

Answer (score 4):

So, $$\frac{\sin x}{-2}=\frac{\cos x}3=\pm\frac{\sqrt{\sin^2x+\cos^2x}}{\sqrt{(-2)^2+3^2}}=\pm\frac1{\sqrt{13}}$$

So, if $\sin x=\mp\frac2{\sqrt{13}},\cos x=\pm\frac3{\sqrt{13}}$

Now as $\frac{5\pi}2<x<3\pi,$ x lies in the second Quadrant.

Using "[All Sin Tan Cos](http://www.knightswoodsecondary.org.uk/personal/Resources/Worksheets/trig5.pdf)" formula, $\sin x>0$ and $\cos x<0$

So, $\sin x=\frac2{\sqrt{13}}, \cos x=-\frac3{\sqrt{13}}$

Answer (score 3):

$$
\frac{\sin x}{\cos x} = \frac{-2}{3} = \frac{-2/\sqrt{(-2)^2+3^2}}{3/\sqrt{(-2)^2+3^2}} = \underbrace{\frac{-2/\sqrt{13}}{3/\sqrt{13}} = \frac{2/\sqrt{13}}{-3/\sqrt{13}}}_{\text{Which  one of these?}}.
$$

One divides by $\sqrt{(-2)^2+3^2}$ in order to make the squares of the numerator and denominator add up to $1$, since one must have $\sin^2 x+\cos^2 x = 1$.

One chooses between the two alternatives over the $\underbrace{\text{underbrace}}$ by looking at which quadrant one is in.  In that quadrant, the sine is positive and the cosine is negative.

Answer (score 2):

From $\frac{5\pi}2<x<3\pi$, we conclude that $\sin x>0$, $\cos x<0$.
Now from $$\frac49=\tan^2x =\frac{\sin^2 x}{\cos^2 x}=\frac{\sin^2 x}{1-\sin^2x}$$
we obtain
$$\frac49(1-\sin^2x)=\sin^2x$$
hence $$\sin^2 x=\frac4{13},\qquad \cos^2 x=1-\sin^2x=\frac9{13}$$
and ultimately (using the above remark about the signs)
 $$\sin x=\frac2{\sqrt{13}},\qquad \cos x=-\frac3{\sqrt{13}}.$$

Comment: This answer seems more complicated than it needs to be.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the trigonometric identity:

$$\sec^2 x = \tan^2 x + 1.$$

Since $\sec x = \frac{1}{\cos x},$
this implies that

$$|\cos x \,| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\tan^2 x + 1}}.$$

Note that $\tan (x + \pi) = \tan x$, 
but $\cos (x + \pi) = -\cos x,$
so we really do need the absolute value function (or a $\pm$ sign)
in the equation above.
Additional information is needed in order to decide whether
to use the positive or negative value of $\cos x$;
if we are given that $\frac52 \pi < x < 3\pi$
then we should use the negative value (since $\cos x < 0$ for every such $x$),
hence

$$\cos x  = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{\tan^2 x + 1}} = -\frac{3}{\sqrt{13}}.$$

For $\sin x$, simply take

$$\sin x = (\cos x)(\tan x)
 = \left(-\frac{3}{\sqrt{13}}\right)\left(-\frac23\right) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{13}}.
$$

---

If we did not already know that $\cos x < 0$ from the restriction
$\frac52 \pi < x < 3\pi,$ we would have to take other measures to
deal with the sign of $\cos x$.
For example, if we know that $2\pi < x < 3\pi,$
then that alone does not tell us whether $\cos x$ 
should be positive or negative;
but since $\sin x > 0$ for every $x$ in that range and we are given
that $\tan x = -\frac23 < 0$, then
$\cos x = \frac{\sin x}{\tan x} < 0.$