# Is there any method to calculate $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ without calculating $x$ if I know $\tan(x)$?

Tags: trigonometry

For example, if I know $\tan(x)=1.2345$, is there any method to calculate the value of $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ without using $\tan(x)$ or calculating $x$ first?

Comment: Interesting question, but this has nothing to do with JavaScript. You might better ask at [math.SE], it's off-topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: Whats stopping you from calculating x first?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compute $\cos$ and $\sin$ in a given interval if I know $\tan$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318001/how-do-i-compute-cos-and-sin-in-a-given-interval-if-i-know-tan)

Answer (score 5):

It is not that difficult:

```
sin(x)² + cos(x)² = 1
```

so

```
(sin(x) / cos(x))² + 1 = 1/cos(x)²
```

so

```
tan(x)² + 1 = 1/cos(x)²
```

so

```
cos(x)² = 1/(tan(x)² + 1)
```

In Javascript:

```
var tanX = 1.2345;
var cosX = Math.sqrt(1/(tanX*tanX+1));
```

Refer to this list of [trigonometric identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Related_identities)!

Answer (score 1):

It is really a math question..
Think that $\tan(x)=\sin(x)/\cos(x)\implies (\tan(x)^2)(\cos(x)^2) = \sin(x)^2$ .

As $\cos(x)^2 = 1 - \sin(x)^2$:

$\tan(x)^2 - (\tan(x)^2)(\sin(x)^2) = \sin(x)^2$

Therefore, 
$\sqrt{\frac{\tan(x)^2}{\tan(x)^2 + 1}} = \pm\sin(x)$